# How to make specific elements static in a non-static ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, static

Is there a way to add an static element in a non-static ArrayList?

I have my Collaborator class, and this class has a Projects Arraylist. The thing is, my Project class has a method to edit a project, but when I edit, it doesn't update the element in the Project ArrayList in the collaborators I've created.

Updating manually would require me to run the Projects Arraylist inside my Collaborators ArrayList to search which collaborators have this project I'm editing.

I've created a static Project object in Main class, and when I edit him, it seems to work. But I can't create static objects inside methods.

```
class Collaborator {
String name;
String email;
ArrayList<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
```

I tried to make the whole ArrayList static, but it makes all new collaborators I create have the same projects, which I don't want to happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand this correctly: The edits in a Project instance are not reflected in the Project instance in the list?

Comment: Show the method you use to add an instance of a `Project` class to the `projects` ArrayList in the `Collaborator` class.

Comment: "my Project class has a method to edit a project, but _when I edit_, it doesn't update the element". How are invoking the method to edit an instance of the `Project` class?

Comment: This question sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You _think_ you need to do X to solve some issue you haven't disclosed, when the real issue is Y.  Tell us what the real issue is.

Comment: I would suggest that perhaps somewhere you are taking a copy of a Project and editing the copy, not the original? Check where your're putting Projects into the arraylist, where you're getting them out, and where you're editing them. If you use anything like projects.add(new Project(y)) then you are putting a copy of the original 'y' project in there, and when you edit 'y', the copy will not change.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm a beginner to Java. 
I wasn't editing to project correctly. @Chunko, you're right. I wasn't editing the right project, but a copy, that's why I thought in Java it created a copy instead of passing the reference.

Comment: Good to see it helped. Since my suggestion was correct, I have added it as an Answer, perhaps you could mark it as accepted. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that perhaps somewhere you are taking a copy of a Project and editing the copy, not the original?

Check where you're putting Projects into the arraylist, where you're getting them out, and where you're editing them - if you use anything like:

```
projects.add(new Project(y))
```

then you are putting a copy of the original 'y' project in there, and when you edit 'y', the copy will not change.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make specific elements static in a non-static ArrayList?

It is not possible.

It doesn't even make sense.

The `static` keyword only makes sense for variables and methods (and classes in a different context).  And element of a collection is not a variable.

If you showed us the relevant parts of your code, we could maybe advise what you *should* do.  But your current approach is (as they say) "barking up the wrong tree".

---

> My Project class has a method to edit a project, but when I edit, it doesn't update the element in the Project ArrayList in the collaborators I've created.

There are a number of possible explanations for that.  But we would need to see the code:

- where you declare and initialize the `ArrayList` and add the `Project` to it
- where you call the method to edit the `Project`, and
- the code (method?) that does the `Project` editing.

Comment: can you display the main function?

Comment: @AbdelmjidELKIHEL - Are you talking to me?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't make sense. I'm a beginner to Java, I thought when adding an object to an ArrayList, it created a copy, but it adds the reference, like a pointer. Thanks for your answer. The reason I thought it created a copy is because I was editing it wrongly, so it wasn't updating. But thanks to the answers here I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your problem completely but still trying to help you in resolving the issues.

> I have my Collaborator class, and this class has a Projects Arraylist. The thing is, my Project class has a method to edit a project, but when I edit, it doesn't update the element in the Project ArrayList in the collaborators I've created.

It is not possible if you are doing things correctly. Say you want to call the method of your `Project` class which does some editing on the object's property. Then you should do something like this.

```
projects.get(i).function_name()
```

You are calling the function of the i'th `Project` object from the `projects` ArrayList which is actually updating the object from the ArrayList.

This part of your question, `my Project class has a method to edit a project, but when I edit` is compelling me to doubt that probably you are doing something wrong.

Editing means, are you updating a project class object? Which object's method you are invoking to update that object? Showing the code will help us more to understand your problem.

I strongly believe you don't need to make your ArrayList static because you can always update a member object of `ArrayList<Project> projects` by invoking the required method of `Project` class.

Comment: I was doing something wrong. I'm a beginner to Java, when I noticed it wasn't updating, I thought, when adding an object to an Arraylist, it created a copy instead of passing the reference. But I was editing it wrongly. I was editing a copy instead of editing the right object. Thanks for your help.